# CKEditor - Why does the anchor feature use a flag icon?

Tags: ckeditor, anchor

This has been driving me crazy when users ask me this.

Why does the anchor feature use a flag for the icon?

I've not found the answer to this is any supporting documentation, google, or in any previous question here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a choice of CK developers I think, it is possible to change the icon if you wish.